# Regarding errno and strerror()

Tags: c, arguments, evaluation, errno

Considering `fopen()` fails, in the following piece of code:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error occurred while opening file, errno=%d, %s\n", 
                         errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Since the order in which function arguments are evaluated is unspecified in C, while invoking `printf()`, in case call to `strerror()` is evaluated (invoked) first and it fails, wouldn't `errno` [be set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strerror_r.html) to something else when the line actually gets printed? Or, is it that `errno` would have been copied into the activation record of `printf()` even before evaluating `strerror()` and hence would remain unchanged? Is this unspecified behaviour?

**EDIT:**
Yes, I do understand that I can save `errno` to some `int` right after `fopen()`, but that's not my point here. I am trying to figure out how the above piece of code behaves.

Comment: IIRC (and it may be that I don't remember correctly), `strerror()` does not set `errno`.  But it's a good question.  And a safe way to work is to capture `int errnum = errno;` and then use `errnum`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler _"Upon successful completion, `strerror()` shall return a pointer to the generated message string. On error `errno` **may be set**, but no return value is reserved to indicate an error."_ - Not sure if that's in the standard or just in Posix though.

Comment: There is absolutely no point in printing `errno`.  The only thing `errno` is useful for is as an index to find the value of `strerror`.  Error messages that include a numeric value of `errno` are line noise.  But it *is* extremely useful to print the name that was used to access the file, and omitting "file.txt" from the error message is a grave sin.   Many kittens will die when this code is executed.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Agree on not printing the file name – for error numbers only partially. Texts might be translated depending on the locale in use ([*'The contents of the string are locale-specific.'*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror)), numbers remain the same. I personally prefer reading the error *numbers* at least in these cases where I know them by heart anyway. Admitted they get less useful if they are OS- or otherwise dependent...

Comment: @Aconcagua With respect (and I know a few of them, too), *someone who knows errno values by heart is not the normal user who you should be optimizing your program for!* :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit OK, printing console indeed likely is intended for the general user (in contrast to log files) and thus I'd print the error text *first* for sure – but fully omitting the code itself? Id' consider cases, too, where the user calling for support is asked for, if the error is not that obvious as `file does not exist`...

Comment: The C11 standard [§7.24.6.2 The `strerror` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.6.2) does not make any mention of possible failures or setting `errno`.  It does say "`strerror` shall map any value of type `int` to a message".  POSIX permits `strerror()` to fail, but also supports the C standard "_strerror()_ shall map any value of type **int** to a message` — so you should always get a message back, even if it is not "properly localized".

Comment: @WilliamPursell Think of printing the actual `errno` value as a checksum on the message text the user is going to put into the bug report.  That's not "line noise" at all.

Comment: The lack of the file name in the error message could be, in part, because it would require repeating a literal string.  I'd go so far as to argue that it is never correct to call `fopen()` with a literal string for the file name, precisely so that you have a variable pointing the name and can use that pointer when formatting the error message.  I'd argue that the file name is more important than the system error message — given a choice between including the file name and the output from `strerror()`, it is far more important to include the file name than the system error string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Any library function can set `errno` to a nonzero value whether or not there is an error (C11 7.5/4).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Is there any standard anywhere that mandates `errno` be consistent?  On your machine, errno == 13 is a permission error. On my machine, errno 13 may be something else.  Unless there is some standard that mandates those values match, it is not useful as a checksum and indeed would lead to confusion rather than clarification.

Comment: @AndrewHenle eg, if someone tells me that they got "errno 38: Socket operation on non-socket" and I go to my debian box and see that errno 38 is "Function not implemeted", does the 38 help to clarify or does it obfuscate the problem?  Including errno is not merely line noise; it is potentially incorrect and confusion information.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Even within Linux, not all architectures use the same errno mappings.

Comment: @WilliamPursell *Including errno is not merely line noise; it is potentially incorrect and confusion information*  And asking someone who only speaks Portugese to read an error message that came out in Russian for some reason is more accurate than "Just tell me the number you see." ?!?! If a user can't read a **number**, you can't rely on them to provide an accurate error message.  Your "line noise" is the most concise, accurate way to record the information.  It's the exact **opposite** of "line noise".

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's a valid point, but when the person tells you the number is 38, how does that help?   You can't reliably map that 38 to anything meaningful.  You are speaking to someone who only speaks Portugese whose environment is so fubar that the error messages are in Russian, but you expect to have accurate information about the platform?

Answer (score 5):

> Since no return value is reserved to indicate an error, an application wishing to check for error situations should set errno to 0, then call strerror(), then check errno.

From the same article that you used. Very likely it's unspecified behaviour. MAN tells the same

> POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008 require that a successful call to
> strerror() or strerror_l() shall leave errno unchanged, and note
> that, since no function return value is reserved to indicate an
> error, an application that wishes to check for errors should
> initialize errno to zero before the call, and then check errno
> after the call.

So you can save `errno` of `fopen`, and then get `errno` of `strerror`. Or simply use `perror`.

Answer (score 3):

> Considering `fopen` fails, in the following piece of code:
>
> ```
> FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
> if (fp == NULL) {
>     printf("Error occurred while opening file, errno=%d, %s\n", 
>                          errno, strerror(errno));
>     exit(1);
> }
> ```
>
> Since the order in which function arguments are evaluated is unspecified in C, while invoking `printf`, in case call to `strerror` is evaluated (invoked) first and it fails, wouldn't `errno` be set to something else when the line actually gets printed?

That is indeed possible. Additionally, according to the C standard, `errno` could be set to a nonzero value whether or not there is an error in the call to `strerror` or any other library function provided the use of `errno` is not documented for the function (see C17 7.5/3). However, POSIX (since POSIX.1-2001, and prior to that in 1997's Single UNIX Specification, version 2) guarantees that `strerror` will not change the setting of `errno` if successful.

> Or, is it that `errno` would have been copied into the activation record of `printf` even before evaluating `strerrno()` and hence would remain unchanged? Is this unspecified behaviour?

It is unspecified behaviour. The arguments and function designator can be evaluated in any order (but there is a sequence point before the actual call to the function to avoid evaluations within a function body being interleaved with evaluations within another function body) (see C17 6.5.2.2/10).

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that could occur under Linux as the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) of `strerror()` says in the **NOTES** section that `errno` can be modified by the service:

> POSIX.1-2001 permits strerror() to set errno if the call
> encounters an error, but does not specify what value should be
> returned as the function result in the event of an error.  On
> some systems, strerror() returns NULL if the error number is
> unknown.  On other systems, strerror() returns a string something
> like "Error nnn occurred" and sets errno to EINVAL if the error
> number is unknown.  C99 and POSIX.1-2008 require the return value
> to be non-NULL.